# open up google maps and then go back to flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have an app that can take coordinates and show the location on google maps.

```
    Future<void> _openMap(String lat, String long) async {
          String googleURL =
              'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$lat,$long';
          Uri url = Uri.parse(googleURL);
          launchUrl(url);
    }
```

I want to be able to back to my app after opening the google maps.

Comment: Did you consider to run Google maps in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: I don't think you can put some kind of button within the google maps since it is not customizable. A webview within the app would be a good thing to try.